# Magento on NGINX - Admin only shows blank screen

Tags: php, nginx, magento-1.7

I'm migrating a working magento in a server with Apache2 that's works fine.
But on NGINX, the administrative portal is not working.

When I logon, it's shows a blank screen and my URL changes to mysite/index.php/admin/index/index/key/1a18935bc65e514d379f18c123c2c2e9/

I can see on the Dev Tools a cookie being generated at most.

No errors on screen nor exceptions generated on log as well.

It's too silent

Any clue ?

Btw...this is my config file on NGINX

```
server {
listen 80;

root /usr/share/nginx/dev.unicase.com.br;
index index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name name.of.my.server;

location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}

location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Any light ?? ty !

PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4

Magento : 1.8.0

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is go into /var/log/nginx and checkout error.log -

Nano error.log

If it has to do with an extension for example curl ensure you run the following things

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-(put name of extension here) it could be php5-gd php5-curl php5-mcrypt but make sure you run apt-get update FIRST.
```

If nothing else post that error log!

Also you need to remove your path from root - you can still see the website via that path.